# Promise to God- Anyone?

Tags: gods

I am new to this site and hence wanted to ask a doubt of mine here.I saw a similar thread on this forum but I couldn't get my answer. I wanted to know is somebody out there has the experience which I have described below-

Is there anyone here who prayed God's deity in a temple for some wish and in return took a vow/promise that he/she will do this or that IF God fulfils his/her wish? But after some time he/she fulfilled his vow/promise in advance, before God fulfilled his wish. I mean he fulfilled his part of the deal made to God, in advance before fulfilment of his wish. Will God accept his vow/promise as fulfilled which he fulfilled in advance before his wish got fulfilled?

Let me know if somebody out here did this or has this experience? Or any of their relatives did the same?

Comment: The problem with this type of questions is the answers will be, in most of the cases, opinion/personal experience based.  However, this site mandates that answers  should be backed by scriptures.  And, scriptures do not specifically say about faith based issues.So I doubt if anyone can provide answer for this question.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv There are many instances of a god granting someone a boon after they have completed, for example, tapas. So, it seems this question can be answered from texts. However, as the question stands it does look like it is seeking opinions. So, I suggest someone edit it to be in line with Hinduism.SE standards (rather than voting to close)

Comment: Srinivas,  Hello! Welcome to Hinduism.SE. Here are a few great introductory resources: ( https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask ), ( https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer ), & ( https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/45/10329 ). I do agree with Sriman Narayana that your question looks enough like it's asking for an opinion that either a) people will answer with an opinion instead of quoting a verified source, or b) your question may get closed. Please edit it to fix this potential issue.

Comment: The Lord is not a trader or bookkeeper.

Comment: Why should opinions differ. This question is clearly implying that if God is satisfied then wish is granted. It doesn't work that way in Hinduism. Question can be answered on the basis of Karma theory. Secondly, if the poster details what he is wishing for then the appropriate ritual, vrata etc can be looked up

Comment: Yes I am looking for personal experiences only. If anybody out here has fulfilled his vow in advance? Is there anyone here who prayed God's deity in a temple for some wish and in return took a vow/promise that he/she will do this or that IF God fulfils his/her wish? But after some time he/she decided to fulfill his vow/promise in advance, before God fulfilled his wish. I mean he decided to fulfill his part of the deal made to God, in advance before fulfilment of his wish. Will God accept his vow/promise as fulfilled which he fulfilled in advance before his wish got fulfilled?

Comment: @swami vishwananda...yes sir I fully agree that God is not a trader. But the person who took the vow did not know this earlier and took the vow to do something in return if his wish gets fulfilled. Now if he has taken the vow then after fulfilment of his wish, he should fulfil it na? Otherwise God will become angry

Comment: @srimannarayana k v. ..Ok so what's your opinion about it? A person prayed God's deity in tirupati temple for some wish and in return took a vow/promise that he/she will visit tirupati again IF God fulfils his/her wish? But after some time he/she visited tirupati in advance, before God fulfilled his wish. I mean he fulfilled his part of the deal made to God,by visiting Tirupati in advance before fulfilment of his asked wish. Will God accept his vow/promise of visiting tirupati as fulfilled which he fulfilled in advance before fulfilment of his requested wish?

Comment: If you have used word something like "after" (e.g. **after** completion of wish I will do this) then you have to be on your words. But if you haven't specified any time duration then you can go any time after completion, say one month or 1 year.

Comment: @lazy lubber...I read your answer somewhere here regarding advance fulfilment of Vow but can't find it now. Can you please share your experience?

Comment: @Rishabh. ..and no i did not use the word "after". I used the word "if". Eg- If my wish get fulfilled then I will do this.

Comment: (This is lazy lubber, now under a different name). Yes sir, I already related to you all my experiences. I do not have anything new to add.

Comment: @lazy lubber...shared your experiences to me? I dont get you sir. I saw your and Mr Amit's replies somewhere but couldn't find it now and hence asked you.

Comment: @lazy lubber..may be you are confused because my question is similar to Mr amit. If possible pls share your experience here or on chat.

Comment: @Carmensandiego Questions asking for user's opinions and personal experiences.  Such type of questions are suitable in chat rooms. For the main site, it is off-topic. Personal experience is not considered a source because they are not verifiable by the reader.

Comment: Reddy gaaru, if you want, we can chat sometime during the weekend. Sorry, I thought you were the same as Amit.

Comment: @Rishabh...can you please explain your answer in a simple way?